# How to calculate multiple pole active filter manually?

Tags: filter, band-pass

For example I want to make a 6-pole multiple feedback topology active bandpass filter that have the specifications of 0.25 db chebychev ,  that the range of the filter is 2000 hz to 3000 hz.

I already know how to calculate a single 2-pole filter if I wanted to , but I don't understand how to calculate the filters for each section to make a 6-pole filter.

I know a 6-pole active filter is usually made up of 3 2-pole filter sections connected together.

So How would a person calculate each section required for a filter? I have always used online filter calculators and have never learned how to calculate each section required manually.

Comment: Use the tables for 0.25dB n=6 and normalized  f and Q . The poles follow an ellipical curve.

Comment: 6-pole Chebyshev requires fairly tight component value tolerance. I'd suggest you do a simulation that varies component values to get a feel for what's required to keep within your 0.25 dB spec...every added pole tightens tolerance. https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/ does suggest each component tolerance in their design applet. Don't forget to add parasitic capacitances

Comment: Math https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter. But higher the Q, the tighter the tolerances which increase with f at each stage

Comment: e.g. {fn,q}= 0.444fo Q=0.637, 0.794 fo Q= 1.556, 1.0311fo Q=5.52 for 3 stages

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Where do I find the information you just gave? I tried looking for formulas online , but really having a issue on finding the correct stuff for multi-pole filters. Obviously there are different things that I have found online, just not sure what to use.

Comment: Originally a red book on filter synthesis was used, now the TI simulator makes this easier than duck soup. You can scale all the RC values later but choose any initial tolerances for R,C from the TI filter.  https://www.ti.com/design-resources/design-tools-simulation/filter-designer.html. There used to be an offline version which I have.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I use Ti FilterPro desktop for filter calculations too , I mostly use analogs online filter calculator though.

Answer (score 0):

First find the transfer function for the chebyshev (the tool I usually use is matlab) once you find this you can find a physical realization (sallen-key, state-variable among others) for opamps (or you could just use LC or RC filter components which are more lossy than an active filter). To find the sallen key realization I usually decompose the transfer function into [second order sections](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/filters/PFE_Real_Second_Order_Sections.html) and then match it up with an opamp [second order section](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/sallen-key).

But you don't have to use a second order section to physically realize a filter, you can use any filter topology as long as the transfer function of the opamps sufficiently approximates the transfer function of the elliptic filter design.

If you want to find the Chebyshev transfer function directly it is part of elliptic filter design, which is more information than could fit in an answer, but this is worth a read:
[Lecture Notes on Elliptic Filter Design](https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/ece521/notes.pdf)
I usually leave this to the tools to find as I don't want to rewrite code that is already on my computer.